# Получить строки из файла и записать в массив LUA

Tags: строки, lua

Я имею строку, которую записываю в файл и выходит такой формат записей

```
08.03.2018 в 10:53  Россия
08.03.2018 в 01:54  Нидерланды
07.03.2018 в 22:30  Германия
07.03.2018 в 22:29  Россия
07.03.2018 в 22:08  Россия
07.03.2018 в 20:09  Россия
07.03.2018 в 18:45  Нидерланды
07.03.2018 в 18:14  Япония
07.03.2018 в 16:25  Германия
06.03.2018 в 21:44  Россия
06.03.2018 в 17:19  Германия
06.03.2018 в 17:15  Япония
06.03.2018 в 16:01  Германия
06.03.2018 в 12:01  Россия
05.03.2018 в 23:39  Япония
05.03.2018 в 19:38  Германия
05.03.2018 в 17:46  Россия
05.03.2018 в 17:45  Германия
05.03.2018 в 17:31  Россия
05.03.2018 в 17:21  Германия
```

Дальше я бы хотел разобрать этот файл на отдельные строки, которые записывались бы в массив, а не являлись одним целым. Как составить шаблон для такой операции?

Чтобы это выглядело так:

```
var [1] = "08.03.2018 в 10:53   Россия"
var [2] = "08.03.2018 в 01:54   Нидерланды"
var [3] = "07.03.2018 в 22:30   Германия"
```

И так далее

Comment: Обязательно нужно сначала записывать в файл? Проще распарить изначальную строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как можно разобрать длинную строку на отдельные строки, если внутри есть символ перевода строк '\n' :

```
local s = [[
08.03.2018 в 10:53  Россия
08.03.2018 в 01:54  Нидерланды
07.03.2018 в 22:30  Германия
07.03.2018 в 22:29  Россия
07.03.2018 в 22:08  Россия
07.03.2018 в 20:09  Россия
]]

local t = {}

for line in s:gmatch("(.-)\n") do
  t[#t+1] = line:gsub("\r","") 
end

print(t[1])
print(t[2])
```

файл прочитать построчно можно с помощью io.lines:

```
  local file = "myfile.txt"
  local t= {}
  for line in io.lines(file) do 
    t[#t+ 1] = line
  end
```